# Opensearch with Graylog

Tags: opensearch, graylog

I do have error an error with Opensearch,

I juste recently upgrade Elasticsearch to Opensearch 2.6.x and there's the error I have :

> 2023-03-20T14:53:32.878-04:00 ERROR [PivotAggregationSearch]
> Aggregation search query  returned an error: OpenSearch
> exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Text fields are not
> optimised for operations that require per-document field data like
> aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default.
> Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true
> on [message] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted
> index. Note that this can use significant memory.].

Thank you

I tried to modify the index with

```
  "message": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
```

Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

as reported in the error log, you cannot aggregate over "text" data fields, you need to use a "keyword" data field instead (maybe, defined as a subfield). E.g. new mapping

```
"message": {
    "type": "text",
    "properties": {
      "keyword": { "type": "keyword" }
    }
  },
```